# How is the Java priority Queue supposed to work?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Short story, I'm implementing a graph and now I'm working on the Kruskal, I need a priority queue. My definition of a priority queue is that the element with the smallest key would come first? Is this wrong? Because when I insert the weighted edges(or numbers) in the queue they don't end up sorted.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> tja = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(); 
tja.add(55);
tja.add(99); 
tja.add(1); 
tja.add(102);
tja.add(54);
tja.add(51);
System.out.println(tja);
```

That would print out this; [1, 54, 51, 102, 99, 55]. This is not sorted like I want them to be! And yes I made a comperator that goes into the priority queue that extracts the number from the edge object and compares based on that int. So this should work, or have I just completely misunderstood the entire concept of how this data structure works?

Comment: to get sorted layout you should use
`while (!tja.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(tja.poll());
}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System.out.println is invoking the toString() method, which is using the iterator, which is not guaranteed to respect the natural ordering. From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order."

Comment: So, is there any possibility to print the priority queue?

Comment: Never mind, There is no way to do so... I will update the answer if you let me.

Answer (score 6):

I have no experience with `PriorityQueue` in Java but it looks like the priority thing is not integrated into `iterator()` or `toString()` (which uses `iterator()`).

If you do:

```
    while (tja.size()>0)
        System.out.println(tja.remove());
```

You get the proper results.

Comment: Perfect, so the structure is not sorted properly until you run remove.

Comment: No, the structure is always correctly sorted, just not when you are iterating over it. But if you call poll(), or peek(), or remove(), you get the elements in the correct order.

Comment: @data_hepp No. Remove doesn't sort the structure. The structure is already sorted but toString() or iterator() that it internally uses doesn't guarantee the traversal in order.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with functioning of Binary heaps? If not please go through min heap and max heap structures. PriorityQueue is implemented on heaps.
PriorityQueue doesn't sort the items in increasing order, but it does the heap sort on it.

Go through the link: [Priority Queue](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/11.PRIORITY-Q.html)

The output you get is correct.